# Django não valida campos alterados no cliente por JS

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

Meu projeto possui um formulário que um dos campos é lista de objetos(Cursos), porém esses objetos estão sendo passados de outra lista(Cursos da área) por meio de JavaScript, só que os valores alocados com JS para a lista principal(Cursos) não passam da fase de validação do ModelForm. Segue o código:

```py
    class EntidadeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        area = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label='Área',
            queryset=Area.objects.all(),
            required=False,
            empty_label='Selecione uma Área',
            widget=forms.Select(attrs=
                                {'onchange': "filtraCursosCad();"}
                                )
        )
        cursos_da_area = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            label='Cursos da Área',
            queryset=Curso.objects.none(),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs=
                                {'onclick': "adicionaCurso();"}
                                )
        )
        class Meta():
            model=Entidade
            fields=['area','cursos_da_area',
                    'cursos',Outros atributos da entidade...]

        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super(VagaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['cursos'].queryset = Curso.objects.none()
```

Código JS:

```js
//Código que filtra a lista 'mãe'    
function filtraCursosCad(){
        area_id=document.getElementById('id_area').value;
        $.ajax({                       

            url: '/entidade/ajax/carrega_cursos/',
            data: {
              'area': area_id,      
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function (data) {   
              $("#id_cursos_da_area").html(data);  
            }
        });
    }
    //Código que adiciona o curso
    function adicionaCurso(){
        $("#id_cursos").append( $("#id_cursos_da_area option:selected"));
    }
```

Código usado na view:

```
class EntidadeCriar(CreateView):
    model=Entidade
    form_class =EntidadeForm

    def form_valid(self,form):
        entidade=form.save(commit=False)
        entidade.empresa=self.request.user.empresa
        entidade.save()
        return redirect('entidade_empresa')
```

**Solução**

Seguindo o que o @Eric Chiesse disse troquei o código do preenchimento do campo cursos que agora está assim:

```
self.fields['cursos'].queryset = Curso.objects.all()
```

Além disso também me baseando na resposta dele fui montar um código JS para "limpar" o campo no momento em que a página é carregada, então encontrei o evento [onload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) e então tentei vinculá-lo ao componente Select do Html porém não tive sucesso e pesquisando descobri que esse evento não está disponível para todas as tags html([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)), então fiz uma chamado do onload no body que ficou assim:

```
<body onload="zeraCursos()">
```

e o código JS ficou assim:

```
function zeraCursos(){
    var cursos=document.getElementById("id_cursos");

    for(var i = cursos.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        cursos.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você verificou que tipo de informação você está enviando para o servidor (Console do navegador/Rede) e o que está chegando nele (`request.POST`)?

Comment: Cara pelo que olhei na aba network do Firefox é um "array" de inteiros, para fins de teste criei outra entidade manytomany no form da maneira normal e no post os valores selecionados estavam de forma semelhante ao array alterado

Comment: Olá viva, podes partilhar o teu models dos objectos e onde tens a validação do  if form.is_valid():? Partilha o código mais completo possível para te podermos ajudar de forma mais acertiva.

Comment: Vou editar pra acrescentar mais informações aqui

Comment: Oi na linha entidade=form.save(commit=False), coloca um break point, inspeciona o "form" e partilha os attributos que recebes quando fazes POST. Outra questão, onde denfines qual o partial de HTML que vais utilizar na form no class EntidadeCriar(CreateView): não estás a definir, estás a definir no urls.py?

Comment: Tens de confirmar se os fields que retorna no "form", (fazendo debug), e se tem o match com o fields=['area','cursos_da_area',...etc] uma vez que não partilhas todo o código, será difícil obteres uma reposta 100%, sugiro que partilhes o teu projeto no gihhub e partilhas, para obteres ajuda mais rápida, isto é se puderes partilhar o o teu projeto repositório público.

Comment: Você percebeu que tem o model na tua View está digitado errado `Endidade`?

Comment: Foi apenas um erro ortográfico, acabei de corrigir obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de validação ocorre porque você está colocando `queryset=Curso.objects.none()` em `cursos_da_area = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Os valores do queryset são usados exatamente para validar a entrada do usuário. Quando você especifica o queryset para `Curso.objects.none()` a validação sempre irá falhar pois não há valores para o backend comparar o teu input.

O melhor é você especificar no queryset os valores exatos para validação e trabalhar teu template para inicialmente exibir uma lista vazia. Uma solução rápida é fazer isso via javascript. Então quando você fizer o post para os valores contidos na tua página, mesmo sendo dinâmicos, já estarão contidos no queryset de validação.

Experimenta fazer `queryset=Curso.objects.all()`. Provavelmente já será suficiente.